# Replacing an integer (n) with a character repeated n times

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have a string:

```
"__3_"
```

...which I would like to turn into:

```
"__###_"
```

basically replacing an integer with repeated occurrences of `#` equivalent to the integer value. How can I achieve this?

I understand that backreferences can be used with `str.replace()`

```
var str = '__3_'
str.replace(/[0-9]/g, 'x$1x'))
> '__x3x_'
```

And that we can use `str.repeat(n)` to repeat string sequences `n` times.

But how can I use the backreference from `.replace()` as the argument of `.repeat()`? For example, this does not work:

```
str.replace(/([0-9])/g,"#".repeat("$1"))
```

Comment: `/(x)\1/` matches "xx" where `\1` is a back reference. "$1" is not a back reference, it is a special replacement pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"__3_".replace(/\d/, function(match){ return "#".repeat(+match);})
```

if you use babel or other es6 tool it will be

```
"__3_".replace(/\d/, match => "#".repeat(+match))
```

if you need replace `__11+` with `"#".repeat(11)` - change regexp into `/\d+/`

is it what you want?

According https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

> str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubStr|function)

and if you use function as second param

> function (replacement)
>   A function to be invoked to create the new substring (to put in place of the >substring received from parameter #1). The arguments supplied to this function >are described in the "Specifying a function as a parameter" section below.

Comment: You actually don't need the `+`.

Comment: @ryeballar actually you do. Otherwise `11` would replace with `##` instead of `###########`, etc. Wait nevermind I just looked at the edit, where `+match` was replaced with `match`. But the regexp does need to be changed to `/\d+/g`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts about regexp - possible yes or no -- I'm not sure which logic is needed

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```js
var str = "__3_";

str = str.replace(/[0-9]+/, function(x) {
      
  return '#'.repeat(x);
});

alert(str);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, @Vasiliy answered a little earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Old fashioned approach:

```
"__3__".replace(/\d/, function (x) {
  return Array(+x + 1).join('#');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "__3_";
str = str.replace(/[0-9]/g,function(a){
    var characterToReplace= '#';
    return characterToReplace.repeat(a)
});
```