# Regular Expression of New Line and 5 New Spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I am new to javascript regular expression
Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!
I have this requirement: `\\.sp number\` ->End current output line and skip `<number>` vertical spaces. `<number>` is a positive integer or absent. If `<number>` is absent, skip one space. The horizontal character position remains unchanged.

original text:

```
This is result level note five: This text is highlighted\.sp 5\This sentence should be displayed after 5 new lines.\.ce\This line should be centered.
This sentence should be on a new line.
```

new text:

```
This is result level note five: This text is highlighted<br/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; This sentence should be displayed after 5 new lines.\.ce\This line should be centered.
This sentence should be on a new line.
```

Example of implementation:

```
             test1 = test1.replace(/\\H\\/g,"<b>");
             test1 = test1.replace(/\\N\\/g,"</b>");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing an integer (n) with a character repeated n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507205/replacing-an-integer-n-with-a-character-repeated-n-times)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an optional capturing group to match the digit and use a callback function using replace.

Check if group 1 is defined. If it is, use the number from the group in combination with for example `repeat` to generate the replacement string.

For the demo I have used a newline as the replacement.

```
\\\.sp (\d+)?\\
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fNHCPE/1)

```js
const regex = /\\\.sp (\d+)?\\/g;
const str = `This is result level note five: This text is highlighted\\.sp 5\\This sentence should be displayed after 5 new lines.\\.ce\\This line should be centered.
This sentence should be on a new line.

This is result level note without a number: This text is highlighted\\.sp \\This sentence should be displayed after 1 new lines.\\.ce\\This line should be centered.
This sentence should be on a new line.
`;
const result = str.replace(regex,
  (_, g1) => g1 !== undefined ? "\n".repeat(parseInt(g1, 10)) : "\n\n"
);

console.log(result);
```